# Creating workflow through APEX tooling API

Tags: apex, workflow, tooling-api

There is a very good article with working code available on below link, which shows how to create triggers dynamically from apex classes by using tooling API:

http://www.sundoginteractive.com/sunblog/posts/creating-classes-and-triggers-in-apex-using-the-tooling-api

Similar to this, I would like to generate a workflow dynamically from a Visualforce Page 's custom controller.

If anyone has done similar for dynamic workflow, please share some documentation or reference article.

Thanks and regards,

Ashish Shukla